# When to create and call NSUserActivity becomeCurrent?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

When should I create and call becomeCurrent on NSUSerActivity for screen. On viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? Does it matter?